# change background color of div using color picker

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have created a div, currently when I click it, its color changes from **green** to **red**. I want to add a button, click which a color picker appears and the color I select becomes its background.

Below is my current code of

**home.html**

```
        <div class="stileone">
            Div Content
        </div>

//I want code on this button click to select color from color picker and selected color shall become the div's background color
    <button ion-button (click)="select_color()">Select Color</button>
```

**home.ts**

```
ngOnInit(){
$(".stileone").on("click", function() {
        $(this).css("background", "red");
    }); 
}
```

**home.scss**

```
.stileone {
    background: green
}
```

Please note I am using js in above code and I am fine with it, I can use Ionic or JS, both are ok for me. For HTML manipulation I am using DOM sanitizer, so I can use JS or jQuery for the same.

Comment: `<input type="color"/>` and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color <-- shows you how to handle it being clicked/changed.

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need is :

**Component Side :**

```
color = 'transparent';

select_color(){
    this.color = this.getRandomColor();
}
```

**Template Side :**

```
<div class="stileone"  [ngStyle]="{'background-color': color}">
    Div Content
</div>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-set-bg)**

Comment: when i click on the button, call text picker and i need to select from it, please update the code to achieve this

Comment: your code works but the way i need to implement is not working, can i share team viewer on chat ? I am picking code from local storage and on html i am showing like this - `<div [innerHtml]="code | noSanitize"></div>`

Comment: alright, if you can call html from ts on the html page and then make it work ? you will need a domsanitize pipe..because i am calling html from local storage

Comment: and i used this code on click `      $(".stileone").on("click", function() {
        $(this).css("background", "red");
    }); `   just need to change it to color picker